# Custom font not displaying properly

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to install a custom font on my site. The browser will load the font, but the display is not quite right. The character vertical positions/sizes seem to be off a tiny amounts. See examples
[here](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/1695/text1r.jpg)
and
[here](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/4756/text2a.jpg).

Here is my @font-face declaration:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLT45LightRegular';
    src: url('helvetica-webfont.eot');
    src: url('helvetica-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('helvetica-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('helvetica-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('helvetica-webfont.svg#HelveticaNeueLT45LightRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I used the font squirrel generator to generate this (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Converting fonts for Web use with automated tools often gives unpredictable results, so it's best to use the official Web font edition of whatever typeface you're interested in direct from the relevant foundry when you can. They often adapt and rehint them to look their best in the browser. Doing it this way also ensures the font is correctly licensed for Web use.

Here's the official Linotype-approved [Web font edition of Helvetica Neue 45](http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US/Project/ChooseFonts?ViewDetails=T&ViewFontID=692680) from fonts.com.